# JSP Reporting tools

Tags: jsp, struts2, reporting

I'm working on a web project using Apache Struts2 and Mysql. I need to show some statistics using graphs which should generate according to the data in the database.
Can anyone suggest me a good reporting tool/plug (Java or JavaScript) to draw charts on the web page(if possible to draw). I need the report to be embed in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is the JFreeChart plugin http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/jfreechart-plugin.html This looks good for a quick solution.

For a lot of features, and admittedly not the shortest learning curve is JasperReports.  http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/jasperreports-plugin.html

I'm not a fan of the Struts2 JQuery plugin.  I prefer plain jQuery.  If you're quite comfortable with a client side solution the Struts2 JSON plugin will be useful to get the data you need via ajax. This will be particularly attractive if the chart data is best displayed dynamically. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/JSON%20Plugin

Answer (score 2):

Use fusioncharts :

http://www.fusioncharts.com/free/

I use this once in my application and it works fine.

It's free, open source and easy to use.

Comment: I prefer retrieving data and generate chart
from HTML tables by [fusioncharts-jquery-plugins](http://www.fusioncharts.com/jquery/)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend the [Google Visualization API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/interactive/docs/gallery.html). The charts are HTML5/SVG (using fallbacks for older browsers), so they're interactive.

Comment: The [gvChart plugin](http://www.ivellios.toron.pl/technikalia/2010/06/22/gvchart-plugin-jquery-with-google-charts/) (jQuery with Google Charts) is great, especially generate chart from HTML table. But the Google Chart can't use when offline.

Answer (score 0):

[Struts2-jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/struts2-jquery/wiki/ChartTag) also does charts.